# Disabling Google Chrome Download auto numbering for existing files

Tags: linux, google-chrome, file-download, numbering

When I save a file (e.g. Images) to a folder which already exist there, Chrome adds a `(N)` where `N` is first available number.
This causes I have multiple copies of same file!
How can I disable Chrome's auto file renaming?

Thanks

Comment: @arulappan: the problem is I don't want to re-download anything! I happens alot that I had an image and now I'm saving it again after a while. when I receive "Replace" message I can check the file and don't download it again but Chrome's auto numbering system never alerts me and renames file by itself; I want to disable it!

Comment: But Chrome suggests a name for the file and if it already exists, it adds `(N)`. You can see that when you right-click on an image. The option to `save as` appears. If there's no `(N)`, that means you're saving the image for the first time (in that folder). If there is an `(N)`, that indicates to you that you already have a file by that name (without the `(N)`). So what is the difficulty?

Comment: @vasa1: When I'm doing bunch of save files I hit Enter faster than I look the file name so I should go and delete that duplicated file. after that simply I don't want this **fantastic** and **uinque** feature!! (that Google may consumed lots of money and time to make that without settings!!); it is not a strange thing that I expect some On/Off stuff for that!! is it? nevertheless Chrome's configuration sucks!!

Comment: As this feature in in queue, alternatively you can run a duplicate image file remover in your local folders :)

Comment: Over 5 years later, and this question is still valid. Chrome developers just don't listen! And, nobody seems to understand OP's question properly. On finding a duplicate download, Chrome should have default option setting to - (1) reject (2) replace (3) add number to file like it does presently.

Comment: Sometimes the filename is the same but the file is not the same. I prefer to run `fdupes` or similar on the Downloads folder every once in a while

Answer (score 8):

As of now this is not possible but there is a feature request, see discussion here:

https://crbug.com/68108

Answer (score 7):

The [Downloads Overwrite Existing Files](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/downloads-overwrite-exist/fkomnceojfhfkgjgcijfahmgeljomcfk) extension will overwrite the file if you already have one with the same filename.

Doesn't check if they're the same file contents.

Comment: Getting this **404. That’s an error.**. I have found this one **Downloads Overwrite Already Existing Files** https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/downloads-overwrite-alrea/lddjgfpjnifpeondafidennlcfagekbp

Answer (score 2):

It's not very usable, but there is a way to replace an existing file without installing extensions.
If you just keep the same file name, Chrome will create a new file and auto-number it.

But if you actually click on the target file and click on Save, although the file name is exactly the same, this time Chrome will ask you if you want to replace it:

[image]

I tried the above on a Mac, but I have no reason to believe Chrome would behave differently on other OS's (at least in this respect).

This only works when you can select the destination folder, e.g. when you click on "Save Link As..." or enable [Ask where to save each file before downloading](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95574) in Settings.

Comment: Why the downvote? All other answers here (all upvoted) talk about replacing the file as a way to avoid creating new copies...

Answer (score 1):

The [Have I Downloaded This Before?](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/have-i-downloaded-this-be/apjambapclnlphnllchfdlmhaijeamah?utm_source=plus) extension detects whether a similar download has already been completed and gives you the option to cancel the download and open the existing file. Only works on Linux, so well suited for OP.

Answer (score 1):

The extension that was accepted as the answer no longer exists on the store or Hannos' answer.

I guess this extension might see the same fate.

Here's one that does the same.

**Downloads Overwrite Already Existing Files**

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/downloads-overwrite-alrea/lddjgfpjnifpeondafidennlcfagekbp